# drawing lines and distance to them on image opencv python

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, distance, detection

I encountered such a problem: I can not draw lines on the image where the color was determined, and also find out the distance to this place. Help to make it as in the image below: [image]

My code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from PIL import ImageGrab



    while True:
        screen = np.array(ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(0,40,800,640)))
        rgb_screen = cv2.cvtColor(screen, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

        lower = np.array([72, 160, 160])
        upper = np.array([112, 249, 249])


        mask = cv2.inRange(rgb_screen, lower, upper)
        output = cv2.bitwise_and(rgb_screen, rgb_screen, mask=mask)

        cv2.imshow('window', output)
        if cv2.waitKey(25) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            cv2.destroyAllWindows()
            break
```

Comment: If you have the coordinates of the lines you can use [line](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4.13.4/modules/core/doc/drawing_functions.html#line) of OpenCV and for the text, use [putText](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4.13.4/modules/core/doc/drawing_functions.html#puttext) with the text you desire and the coordinates where you desire

Comment: @api55, no, unfortunately, I do not have coordinates

Comment: Then it sounds like a broad problem with several possible solutions, you should try  some idea to get the coordinates and if you are stuck come here :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't help much because I do not have your original image. But you could read my code and maybe get an idea. For distance I do not know what u mean, so I made an example on how to get distance of top left corner to bottom left. You can apply other points or apply it as ratio depanding on your demands.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('untitled.png')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ret, threshold = cv2.threshold(gray,150,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
im, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(threshold,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
area = sorted(contours, key=cv2.contourArea, reverse=True)
c = area[0]
rect = cv2.minAreaRect(c)
box = cv2.boxPoints(rect)
print(box)
box = np.int0(box)
cv2.drawContours(img,[box],0,(0,0,255),2)
extreme_left = tuple(c[c[:, :, 0].argmin()][0])
extreme_top = tuple(c[c[:, :, 1].argmin()][0])
x1 = box[1,0]
y1 = box[1,1]
x2 = box[0,0]
y2 = box[0,1]
distance = np.sqrt( (x1 - x2)**2 + (y1 - y2)**2 )
font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX
cv2.putText(img,'Distance: '+str(distance),(1,300), font, 0.5,(255,255,255),2,cv2.LINE_AA)
cv2.circle(img, (x2,y2), 5, (255, 0, 0), -1)
cv2.circle(img, (x1,y1), 5, (255, 0, 0), -1)
cv2.imshow('image', img)
```

[image]